# Python: how to create a file .txt and record information in it

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a file .txt and save the information that the user gives and also open the file in python
i'm having trouble in create the file

here is my code

```
from Tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()
frame = Frame(raiz)

def cadastro():
    form = Toplevel(raiz)

    Label(form, text='Nome: ').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=E)
    Label(form, text='Celular: ').grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=E)

    nome = StringVar()
    celular = StringVar()

    a=Entry(form, textvariable=nome, width=15)
    a.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=W)
    Entry(form, textvariable=celular, width=15).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

    def onCancel():
        form.destroy()

    def onOk():
        ******.insert('','end',text=nome.get(), values=celular.get())
        onCancel()

    Button(form, text='OK', command=onOk).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=E)
    Button(form, text='Cancel', command=onCancel).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)

def listar():





w = Button(raiz, text='Cadastrar',command=cadastro).grid()
x = Button(raiz, text='Listar').grid()


raiz.mainloop()
```

the **** it's where i put the file name
Thank you very much in advance

Comment: that's the worst variable naming scheme I've ever seen and what's it with the function ` listar(): `

Comment: it's in my language sorry if you can't understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the code, I redesigned it to meet your requirements. Feedback would be much appreciated

```
from Tkinter import *

raiz = Tk()
frame = Frame(raiz)
out = []

def cadastro():
    form = Toplevel(raiz)

    Label(form, text='Nome: ').grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=E)
    Label(form, text='Celular: ').grid(column=0, row=1, sticky=E)

    nome = StringVar()
    celular = StringVar()

    a=Entry(form, textvariable=nome, width=15)
    a.grid(column=1, row=0, sticky=W)
    Entry(form, textvariable=celular, width=15).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=W)

    def onCancel():
        form.destroy()

    def onOk():
        with open('outt.txt','w') as txt:
            txt.write('Name : ' + str(nome.get()) + '  ' + 'Telephone No. : ' + str(celular.get()))
        onCancel()

    Button(form, text='OK', command=onOk).grid(column=0, row=2, sticky=E)
    Button(form, text='Cancel', command=onCancel).grid(column=1, row=2, sticky=W)

def listar():
    with open('outt.txt','r') as txt_read:
        print txt_read.read()




w = Button(raiz, text='Cadastrar',command=cadastro).grid()
x = Button(raiz, text='Listar' , command=listar).grid()


raiz.mainloop()
```

after entering data, if you clicked on *listar* you can see the output on the screen *(though you can manually view the data which is saved in .txt file)*

here's a sample:

> Name : **K-DawG**  Telephone No. : **911**

The key here is using the `with as` statement, for more info check out Codeacademy's [course](http://www.codecademy.com/tracks/python) on python

using a list and the  *insert()* method was surely not the best option for this problem but rather if you use my method and write to a .csv file with delimiters the program could finally be worthwhile

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [open built-in](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) to get a file object with writing permissions, and then fill the content using the [write function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.write):

```
file = open('<FILENAME>.txt', 'w')
file.write('first line\n')
file.write('second line\n')
file.close()
```

Check out the linked docs for more info about the open arguments and other useful functions like [writelines](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.writelines).

Comment: I'm trying to create a GUI with Tk, where the user can write his name and cell-phone and when he clicks "ok" it saves in the .txt file, i tried to use this code before but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I found a pretty easy way to abstract the concept of files with python's builtin IO functions. I blogged about it [here](http://www.thefourtheye.in/2013/05/python-equivalent-of-cs-freopen.html)

If you want to write to a file, just do

```
import sys
sys.stdout = open ("Output.txt", "w")
print "Name :", str(nome.get()), "Telephone No :", str(celular.get())
```

and if you want to read from a file, just do

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open ("Input.txt", "r")
print raw_input()
```